# Side effect of the new keyword

Tags: java, oop, keyword

What does someone mean when they say the `new` keyword has side effects? On [SSE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359561/using-static-to-create-an-immutable-object?noredirect=1#comment779609_359561), a comment was given for an answer, but I didn't understand the comment.

> Clearly the factory methods in the question call new, they have side
>   effects. However, that side effect is identical to just calling a
>   public constructor, so they are no more difficult to test than the
>   latter.

The question had to do with using a static method to construct an object with a private constructor. What's the side effect to using the `new` keyword and how am I suppose to create my objects?

Comment: The side effect is creating the new object, no?

Comment: As David has already mentioned " side effect is identical to just calling a public constructor "

Comment: Well, in essence you have to use `new` somewhere in your code, be it directly or via some method. The fact that those methods may have side effects and thus might be harder to test doesn't mean you shouldn't use them. One could argue that factory methods should not be static though as they can't be overridden and thus be mocked/tested easily.

Comment: @AndyTurner - to me it sounds like there is a problem. When someone says side effect it sounds like if you do it beware of certain problems

Comment: Just use ``new``. You're not going to run into any problems except for some very special cases that shouldn't bother you. Just create a ``new Weapon()``.

Comment: @f1sh - what are the special cases, just in the interest of learning?

Comment: @S.R. you might not want to care about which subclass of ``Weapon`` is really created, so you let a factory method create it for you (which uses ``new`` as well). You might also use Dependency Injection and have an instance injected instead of creating it yourself. You can also create instances using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--).

Comment: @f1sh - Since it was immutable, I had the `final` keyword there, just didn't include, that shouldn't bother me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [full comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359562/139641) is:

> Clearly the factory methods in the question call `new`, they have side effects. However, that side effect is identical to just calling a public constructor, so they are no more difficult to test than the latter.

He is saying that the side effect is that a new object is created; but the side effect of invoking `new` in a static factory method is no different from invoking `new` directly.

Comment: To me anyway, I took like someone was taking medication, beware side effects are...etc HA!. I thought there was something wrong with the `new` keyword to create an `object`, use the `new` but beware of some problem.

Comment: @S.R. a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) is a specific term in computer science, it is not necessarily a negative thing.

Comment: @S.R. a side effect is only a problem if you don't expect it and/or it's not desired (and you can't know if it's desired if you don't expect it!). In this case, you want a new object, so it is absolutely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By "side effect", programmers usually mean any effect a function has that isn't fully contained within the function itself. Basically, if the "world" has changed as a result of calling a function, it has side effects. If you can call the function as many times as you want and the "world" doesn't ever change, it doesn't.

Quick example: `System.out.println("Hello world!");` does IO, hence it has side effects. `Math.min(5, 10)` just returns `5` without having any additional effects on anything, hence it has no side effects.

In your example, the function you call seems to do not much except constructing a new object with `new`. Have a look at this example:

```
static Foo createFoo() {
    return new Foo();
}
// ...
while (true) {
    createFoo();
}
```

The obvious side effect we see right away is memory allocation. Calling `createFoo()` will cause a heap memory allocation. Arguably `Math.min(5, 10)` also consumes memory, on the stack, but that memory consumption is temporary and fully contained within the function's execution if you don't explicitly assign the return value yourself, at what point it's the caller who causes the memory consumption. Heap allocation outlives the function call, until it eventually gets cleaned up by the garbage collector.

I guess it's not clear cut when you can speak of "no side effects" in Java, as almost everything can cause a heap allocation and it's usually fine to consider objects to be gone by the time you drop their reference and let the GC clean it up later.